# How to explain this list comprehension?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have below example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def gen_df():
  df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3),columns=list('bde'),index=['utah','ohio','texas','oregon'])
  return df

data = {}
date = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(2):
  data[date.date()] = gen_df()
  date -= datetime.timedelta(days=1) 

k = pd.DataFrame({i:j['d'] for i,j in data.items()})
print(k)
```

Can I explain the last statement (list comprehension)as below code?

```
k={}
for i,j in data.items():
   k.update({i:j["d"]})
print(pd.DataFrame(k))
```

The output is correct,but I am not sure if it really correct or not. It seems to me list comprehension should handle "list" not "dict"
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a dict comprehension, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Replace `i` with `key` and `j` with `value` to give you a better semantic idea of what it means.

Comment: So that's why, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dictionary comprehension, not a list comprehension. There are also set comprehensions.

Dictionary comprehensions are in Python 2.7, as well as in Python 3.0 and up.